# Elasticsearch suggest a location that has number of users around

Tags: elasticsearch

Assume that I have a document of User as below:

```
{  
  id,  
  first_name,  
  last_name,  
  geo // Current location of an online user.  
}
```

I would like to search for a specific user who has a 'geo' that is surrounded by many users within 1km of radius. For example, there are lots of users that visit a place because there is an event there, and I would like to suggest our user that "You should take a look at that place". However, the only thing we know is the geo value of online user, so, we need to have a way to check if these user are all focus on one point at a time or not.
Could I use elasticsearch to perform a query like that and how do I do it?

Comment: Is it correct assumption you are looking for some sort of K-means implementation (based off of geo field) which is built-into Elastic? If yes - then there is Github feature-ticket for that: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5512 (unresolved yet). In meantime there are some alternatives for doing this with Spark. For instance this project might be useful for you: https://github.com/skrusche63/spark-elastic

Comment: Thank you, it is K-means implementation. How could I mark this one as a correct answer?

Comment: I've moved the comment into answer with some additional comments :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the algorithm you are looking for is [K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). If that's the case then there is Elastic github [feature-ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5512) which aims to solve this case natively from Elastic, but still not resolved yet.

There are couple of ML libraries that are organically integrated with Elastic. One of them is [spark-elastic](https://github.com/skrusche63/spark-elastic). I'm sure you can find similar based on additional insights of your problem set :-)

Nevertheless I want to mention that the K-means algorithm requires you to supply `K` (desired number of clusters) in advance. And this is something which requires additional domain knowledge expertise or just experimenting with. I.e. it might happen that in one scenario you would cluster your documents into, let's say 5 clusters, whereas in another scenario the better fit would be 10. Just thinking out loud :)